# Simple jQuery code doesn't work on server, but works locally

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure out what's wrong. Basically I want the message "Thank you for signing up!" to fade in when they've entered a valid email, and the message "Please make sure your email was entered correctly." to fade in  when they enter an invalid email.

In my html I have this:

```
<div id="signUp">
    <form action="" method="post" id="signup">
        <input type="text" class="left" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" value="">
        <input type="submit" id="notify-me" class="button" value="Sign me up!">    
    </form>
</div>
<br>
<p class="hidden">Thank you for signing up!</p>
```

And here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // all jQuery code goes here
    $(".hidden").hide();
    $("form").submit(function() {
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        if(emailReg.test($("input:first").val()) && $("input:first").val() != "")
        {
            $(".hidden").text("Thank you for signing up!").fadeIn(1000);
            var dataString = "email=" + $("input:first").val();
             $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "write.php",
               data: dataString,
               success: function() {
                    $("input:first").val("");
                    return false;
                 }
             });
        }
        else
        {
            $(".hidden").text("Please make sure your email was entered correctly.").fadeIn(500);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: See this edit: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15056644/revisions

Comment: When you say it doesn't work on the server, can you describe what is wrong? What behavior do you see? Is there a live URL to test with?

Comment: It seems like animation is working because the div underneath it moves, but the message doesn't appear. You can see what is happening here chestbumpp.com and if it is working fine for you on chestbumpp.com please let me know. I've tried it on linux and Windows in 4 different browsers.

Comment: Latest Chrome, Safari, and FireFox on OSX all worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I finally found out I had previously set the opacity to zero and I forgot to update the css, so I fixed it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery library probably isn't loaded when running from server. Make sure you link to it correctly.

If it's the case, you can fix it by adding this line to the page's `<head>`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem exists outside of what you've given us. Everything that you have here works perfectly.

Likely scenarios:

1. jQuery isn't being included on the server.
2. Parse error somewhere else in the javascript.

Either one should be easily diagnosed based on the error console.

Comment: Working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/JsPXS/. I couldn't include it in the answer, because I wasn't actually showing any code.

Comment: I honestly don't know what the problem is. I am including jQuery on the server. This is the entire script, so I don't think there is a parse error somewhere else in the javascript.There aren't any errors in the console either.